# Variable not defined in EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I would like to know how to access/get an object inside an object in EJS.
When I try to use the object rendered by the server in EJS, I receive the following error:

**`ser.js`:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) { 
    var obj = {"cn": "TH", "contact": {"name": "contactus"}, "about": {"name": "aboutus"}}
    res.render('index.ejs', {result: obj});
})
```

**`index.ejs`:**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/en/<%=result['contact']['name']%>">Contact</a> 
// should be /en/contactus
```

**Error:**

```
contact is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:592:12), <anonymous>:47:25)
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:592:12), <anonymous>:62:10)
    at returnedFn (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:623:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:480:10)
    at View.render (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Projects\pro\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at util.getJsonData.then.data (C:\Projects\pro\routes\language.js:18:27)
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: @jro thanks for reply but getting error contact not defined

Comment: @jro Expected Output should be  `/en/contactus` in href

Comment: Maybe res is a reserved ejs variable, you should change it to something else. I'm not too sure though

Comment: @jro tried with different object name but not working, still same issue

Comment: Could you put the exact error and stacktrace in your question

Comment: @jro updated the ques and code

Comment: did you try `href="/en/<%= result.contact.name %>"`

Comment: @dimitristseggenes thanks for reply ,yes not working , still same issue

Comment: hey, your code looks ok to me. And it is also showing this `/en/contactus`  after clicking the `Contact` link